# xslt 1 : check if node contains any value from list

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to tranform a XML document from one format to a other, and that is all dandy. Now the hard part is that I need to check all lines for a status code, and need to return true/false depend if any code element have any of this codes.

```
<xml>
  <line>
    <id>1</id>
    <code>109</code>
  </line>
  <line>
    <id>2</id>
    <code>065</code>
  </line>
  <line>
    <id>3</id>
    <code>405</code>
  </line>
  <line>
    <id>4</id>
    <code>101</code>
  </line>
</xml>
```

The document I tranform to keep a copy of all line element, but have a extra field, where is set to true/false depend if the any code is in the list.

So I need to compare this list of data to every code and return true if just one of them is in the list
`"101","102","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","110","111"`

Is there any fix mode to make this so I don't need 11 compare stament ?

Ohh and the output look some thing like

```
<System>
  <Route>true</Route> <!-- will be false if the <code> from the first document is not in the list of elements -->
  <Status>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Code>109</Code>
  </Status>
  <Status>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Code>065</Code>
  </Status>
  <Status>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Code>405</Code>
  </Status>
  <Status>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Code>101</Code>
  </Status>
<System>
```

Comment: So how to want or how do you can pass that "list" of codes to XSLT? As an XML document? Then e.g. `//code = document('codes.xml')//code` will give the boolean value you are looking for. If you pass in an argument as a string of values then there is the old trick of using `//code[contains($codes-param, concat('"', ., '"'))]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="pCodeList" select="'101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <System>
      <Route>
        <xsl:value-of select=
        "boolean(/*/*/code
                        [contains(concat(',', $pCodeList, ','), concat(',', ., ',')
                                  )
                        ]
                )"/>
      </Route>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </System>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="line">
    <Status><xsl:apply-templates/></Status>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<xml>
    <line>
        <id>1</id>
        <code>109</code>
    </line>
    <line>
        <id>2</id>
        <code>065</code>
    </line>
    <line>
        <id>3</id>
        <code>405</code>
    </line>
    <line>
        <id>4</id>
        <code>101</code>
    </line>
</xml>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<System>
   <Route>true</Route>
   <Status>
      <id>1</id>
      <code>109</code>
   </Status>
   <Status>
      <id>2</id>
      <code>065</code>
   </Status>
   <Status>
      <id>3</id>
      <code>405</code>
   </Status>
   <Status>
      <id>4</id>
      <code>101</code>
   </Status>
</System>
```

**When the same transformation (above) is applied on this XML document:**

```
<xml>
    <line>
        <id>1</id>
        <code>509</code>
    </line>
    <line>
        <id>2</id>
        <code>065</code>
    </line>
    <line>
        <id>3</id>
        <code>405</code>
    </line>
    <line>
        <id>4</id>
        <code>501</code>
    </line>
</xml>
```

**it again produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<System>
   <Route>false</Route>
   <Status>
      <id>1</id>
      <code>509</code>
   </Status>
   <Status>
      <id>2</id>
      <code>065</code>
   </Status>
   <Status>
      <id>3</id>
      <code>405</code>
   </Status>
   <Status>
      <id>4</id>
      <code>501</code>
   </Status>
</System>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre just what I was after. Will cut down on the xslt file alot.